# How to sort options values for multiple select attributes?

Tags: admin, attributes, sorting

I have a large list of option for the "manufacturer" multi-select attribute.

When I add a new manufacturer, it's going to be on top of the list. I'd like to sort all those options in alphabetical order so that when a store manager adds a new product, he will find it easily in the "Manufactures" drop down menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put the same value in "Position" for all options of the attribute, then at least on my version (EE 1.14.2.2), it alphabetizes the values automatically.